# How to draw a square with dimensions given by the user in Assembly language?

Tags: loops, assembly, draw

I have this so far, but I think the problem in the code lies in how the screen clears? Also, if I use "mov ah, 7 & int 21h" as getch(), would it work if the variables I compare them to are byte-sized, while "mov ah, 0 & int 16h" works for when the variables are word-sized?

```
.model tiny
.code
org 100h    

project:
call ClearScreen
mov ah, 0
int 16h
mov xlimit, ax  ; number of "rows"
mov ah, 0
int 16h
mov ylimit, ax  ; number of "columns"
call border
int 20h

clearScreen:
mov ah, 7
mov al, 25
mov ch, 0
mov cl, 0
mov dh, 24
mov dl, 79
int 10h
mov ah, 2
mov bh, 0
mov dh, 0
mov dl, 0
int 10h
ret
; ----------------------------------------------------
border:
    mov dh, 0
    mov dl, 0
    mov ah, 2
    int 10h
    mov dl, 95
    int 21h
    mov cx, xlimit 

bucle:
    mov dl, cl
    mov dh,0
    int 10h
    mov dl, 95
    int 21h
    mov dx, ylimit
    mov dh, dl
    mov dl, cl
    int 10h
    mov dl, 95
    int 21h
loop bucle
    mov cx, ylimit
    xor dh, dh

bucle2:
    mov dl, 0
    mov dh, cl
    int 10h
    mov dl, 95
    int 21h
    mov dx, xlimit
    mov dh, cl
    int 10h
    mov dl, 95
    int 21h
loop bucle2
ret

; ---------------------------------------------------
; global variables

ylimit dw ?
xlimit dw ?
end project
```

Comment: How come there is an error when the printing square whenever I try to make xlimit larger than 38?

Answer (score 1):

```
mov ah, 0
int 16h
mov xlimit, ax  ; number of "rows"
```

This code only waits until a key is pressed and then gives you the ASCII in AL and the scancode in AH. To get a meaningful number you have to convert it to a number.
If p.e. you type a character from "1" to "9" you convert it by subtracting 48 from AL and storing that in *xlimit*. To continu using your limits as word clear AH just before storing into *xlimit*.

```
mov ah, 0
int 16h
sub al, 48
cbw
mov xlimit, ax  ; number of "rows"
```

This comment should actually read *number of columns*

Bonus: Your *clearScreen* routine needs an extra parameter before calling BIOS.

```
clearScreen:
mov ah, 7
mov al, 25
mov bh, 07h  ;Attribute for the blanked area, WhiteOnBlack
mov ch, 0
mov cl, 0
mov dh, 24
mov dl, 79
int 10h
mov ah, 2
mov bh, 0
mov dh, 0
mov dl, 0
int 10h
ret
```

Answer (score -2):

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
   menu db 'MENU:',13,10,'[A] Horizontal',13,10,'[B] Vertical',13,10,'[C] Diagonal',13,10,'Choice: $'
   msg db 13,10,'Enter number of display: $'
   height db 6
   length db 0
   hash db '#$'
   msgagain db 13,10,'Do you want to try again? $'
   msgtry db 13,10,'Invalid input! Press any key to reset the program..$'
   msgend db 13,10,'Program terminated! Press any key to exit...$'
.code
   mov ax, @data
   mov ds, ax
RESET:   
   mov ax, 03
   int 10h

   mov height, 6

   mov ah, 09
   lea dx, menu
   int 21h

   mov ah, 01
   int 21h

   cmp al, 'A'
   je HOR
   cmp al, 'a'
   je HOR
   cmp al, 'B'
   je VER
   cmp al, 'b'
   je VER
   cmp al, 'C'
   je DIAG
   cmp al, 'c'
   je DIAG
   jmp reset

HOR:       
   mov ah, 09
   lea dx, msg
   int 21h

   mov ah, 01
   int 21h

   cmp al, '1'
   jl ERR
   cmp al, '9'
   jg ERR

   sub al, 30h
   mov bl, 1
   mul bl

   mov cx, ax
   hashhor:
      mov ah, 09
      lea dx, hash
      int 21h
   loop hashhor
   jmp EXIT

ERR:
   mov ah, 09
   lea dx, msgtry
   int 21h

   mov ah, 01
   int 21h  

   jmp RESET

VER:

   mov ah, 09
   lea dx, msg
   int 21h

   mov ah, 01
   int 21h

   cmp al, '1'
   jl ERR
   cmp al, '9'
   jg ERR

   sub al, 30h
   mov bl, 1
   mul bl

   mov cx, ax
   hashver:
      mov ah, 02
      mov bh, 00
      mov dl, 0
      mov dh, height
      int 10h

      mov ah, 09
      lea dx, hash
      int 21h 

      inc height
   loop hashver
   jmp EXIT


DIAG:
   mov ah, 09
   lea dx, msg
   int 21h

   mov ah, 01
   int 21h

   cmp al, '1'
   jl ERR
   cmp al, '9'
   jg ERR

   sub al, 30h
   mov bl, 1
   mul bl

   mov cx, ax
   hashdiag:
      mov ah, 02
      mov bh, 00
      mov dl, length
      mov dh, height
      int 10h

      mov ah, 09
      lea dx, hash
      int 21h 

      inc length
      inc height
   loop hashdiag  

EXIT:
   mov ah, 09
   lea dx, msgagain
   int 21h

   mov ah, 01
   int 21h

   cmp al, 'n'
   je FIN
   cmp al, 'N'
   je FIN  
   jmp RESET

FIN:
   mov ah, 09
   lea dx, msgend
   int 21h

   mov ah, 01
   int 21h

   mov ah, 4ch
   int 21h

END HORIZONAL,DIAGONAL,VERTICAL LOOP
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.